# Terraform bigtable module create multiple table at once

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Hi I am using the below mention terraform to create bigtable cluster and table I want to create multiple tables at a time

## Module

```
 resource "google_project_service" "gcp_services" {
  for_each = toset(var.gcp_service_list)
  project  = var.project_id
  service  = each.key
}

resource "google_bigtable_instance" "instance" {
  name                = var.bigtable_instance_name
  project             = var.project_id
  deletion_protection = var.deletion_protection
  labels              = var.labels

  cluster {
    cluster_id   = var.bigtable_cluster_name
    zone         = var.zone
    storage_type = var.bigtable_storage_type
    autoscaling_config {
      min_nodes  = var.min_nodes
      max_nodes  = var.max_nodes
      cpu_target = var.cpu_target
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.gcp_services
  ]
}
    
  resource "google_bigtable_table" "table" {
  count = var.bigtable_count
  name = element(var.bigtable_table_name, count.index)
  instance_name = google_bigtable_instance.instance.name
  split_keys = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"]
  project = var.project_id

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  column_family {
    family = lookup(var.family_type, element(var.bigtable_table_name, count.index ), [] )
  }
}
```

## var file

```
variable "bigtable_count" {
  type = number
}
variable "family_type" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "test-bigtable-tablename"= ["r", "s"]
    "test2-bigtable-tablename"= ["r", "o"]
  }
}
```

#Error

```
 on ../../main.tf line 48, in resource "google_bigtable_table" "table":
│   48:     family = lookup(var.family_type, element(var.bigtable_table_name, count.index ), [])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ var.bigtable_table_name is a list of string, known only after apply
│     │ var.family_type is a map of list of string, known only after apply
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "family": string required.
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: I have updated the question, and error details can you check it

Answer (score -1):

You don't need question marks around `[]`. It should be:

```
lookup(var.family_type, element(var.bigtable_table_name, count.index ), [])
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, got new Error updated in Question

Comment: @AshokReddy If you have new error, then new question should be made, rather then updating the old question. My current answer correctly addresses the error you reported.

Comment: No after updating your suggestion still getting Error, can you please check the Error once 

on ../../main.tf line 48, in resource "google_bigtable_table" "table":
│   48:     family = lookup(var.family_type, element(var.bigtable_table_name, count.index ), [])


│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ var.bigtable_table_name is a list of string, known only after apply
│     │ var.family_type is a map of list of string, known only after apply


│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "family": string required